# How to handle mysterious characters?

Tags: office-js

I'm getting text from the document using

```
var doc = context.document;
var originalRange = doc.body;
originalRange.load("text");
return context.sync()
  .then(function () {
    // all sorts of mayhem
  }
```

I then send the text off to the server for some analysis and returning the results. All good.

The user can click on the results and my code finds the sentence in the document, scrolls to it, highlights it, and adds a comment. Still, all good. 
That is, unless the sentence contains some unknown characters.

This text has, what appears to be, carriage returns and/or non-printing characters in the middle of the sentence.

// begin bad sentence

> "your "web server" and "sites"
>
> Under "Default Web Site" you"

// end bad sentence

(Yes, it's poorly written and poorly formatted on purpose)

When I look at what's being sent, I see...

```
"your “web server” and “sites”  Under “Default Web Site” you"
```

When I look at what's being returned, I see...

```
"your “web server” and “sites”  ��Under “Default Web Site” you"
```

When I search for the text, not surprisingly, I get 0 results.

```
searchResults = context.document.body.search(myText, { matchCase: true, ignorePunct: true, ignoreSpace:true});
```

How can I search for text, and ignore these strange characters? Or, am I capturing the text from the document incorrectly?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: I'm looking at the document.xml (after changing 'docx" extension to "cab") Here's what I'm seeing for that paragraph...

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00A739D5" w:rsidRDefault="00A739D5" w:rsidP="00A739D5">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cs="Calibri"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cs="Calibri"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">your "web server" and "sites" </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:hyperlink r:id="rId7" w:history="1">
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink"/>
                <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cs="Calibri"/>
                <w:color w:val="5FAA02"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t> </w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:hyperlink>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cs="Calibri"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:br/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cs="Calibri"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:br/>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Under "Default Web Site" you </w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

I'm thinking it's the character encoding. This looks like it's not UTF-8, per the asciiTheme & ansiTheme. Those two "<w:br/>"s appear to be in the right place and it would explain the two "unknown" characters. Is there away to convert them over to UTF-8 or do I need to change my $ajax content type?

Comment: Can you just store the original range.text value and then, when the results comeback, pass the original to search() instead of the corrupted returned results?

Comment: That's just it, Rick, it appears the original range text seems to have those strange characters. What didn't show up in my post were two squares in place of those unknown characters. the returned text has two black-diamond question marks.